# library not found after installing Sockitio-swift?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

i am using Sockit IO-Swift library in my current project. after [installing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGRnT.png) Socket.IO-Client-Swift pod file into my project ,then my FMDB library path not found-- error"library not found for -lFMDB". developers please provide me right solution.

Comment: Show your pod file.

Comment: # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, ‘8.0’

target 'Formee' do
  # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Formee

pod 'FMDB'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift'

end

Comment: Edit your question with that, not in comment where it's not formatted and easily readble.

Comment: resolved errror, with manually add sockitio-swift library into my current project. thank you...